# auto scroll to bottom gridview asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid. On clicling addbutton grid will append one empty row. But that pannel should show me the bottom of the page so that user should see the last item. similar to gTalk or chat window in google. Here is my code. How to get the scroll bar position always at the bottom of the page please help me out

```
  <asp:Content ID="Body" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >
window.onload = function() {     var objDiv = document.getElementById("<%=pnl.ClientID%>");     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight; }


</script>
 <ajx:ToolkitScriptManager ID="CalendarAjaxEnabler" runat="server">
    </ajx:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
<uc1:StatusCodes ID="resultBanner" runat="server" />
    <div id="Div" runat="server" class="divFieldRow">           
         <div>
         <center>           
         <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server"  ScrollBars="Both" style="width:auto;height:200px;">
          <asp:GridView ID="gvGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        GridLines="None" AllowSorting="true"                           FooterStyle-BackColor="DimGray" EnableViewState="true" >

                <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField >                     
                       <HeaderTemplate>event</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" Visible='<%# ! IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Desc") %>' />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Desc")%>' MaxLength="255">
                            </asp:TextBox>                                                        
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField Visible = "false">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Id</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id")%>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                   
                </Columns>                
            </asp:GridView>   
            </asp:Panel>              
            </center>
            </div>    

        <br />
        <br />              
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Edit" Style="margin-left: 50px" ID="btnEditevent" OnClick="btnEditEvent_Click" />        
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add" Style="margin-left: 50px" ID="btnAddevent" OnClick="btnAddRowEvent_Click" />       
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate> 
     </asp:UpdatePanel>      
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` at page directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Comment: i have set that but still iam not getting the scroll bar to the bottom of the page after page loading

Comment: Check this article http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx

Comment: yes, you can read the article and if you follow the article, it will work.

Comment: ok one more small question. In that artical they want me to add the script below script manager. but i am not using any script manager in my code.

Comment: that's not an issue, you can simply put that script.

Comment: I have the same scenario to be worked in an update panel. will the same script work?? or any modifications to be done?

Comment: i am getting an error like Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'scrollLeft' is null or not an object  in this line xPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft; in javascript

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript for this ..

```
window.onload = function() {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("<%=pnl.ClientID%>");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

here is the sample aspx file with your requirement.. and its working perfectly

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
     <title>Untitled Page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("<%=pnl.ClientID %>");
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat ="server" Height="200" Width="100%" ScrollBars ="vertical">
        <table border="1" >
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
            <tr><td>this is testing</td></tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u please tell me where to use this exactly i am new to javascript. In the button click event (Add rows btn) for on clientClick event do u want me to call this function? Can you please explain me?

Comment: use this on aspx page.. inside the head tag like this
        <head><script type='text/javascript'>window.onload =....</script></head>

Comment: i used this but after clicking on add the scroll bar is in top position only.

Comment: see the sample aspx file in answer hope you will have some idea :)